# How do you get the identity value after using MERGE when there is a match?

Tags: t-sql

Say I have a table with an identity field. I want to insert a record in it if it doesn't already exist. In the below example, I check if the value stored in @Field1 already exists in the table. If not, I insert a new record:

Definition of the table:

```
MyTable (MyTableId int Identity not null, Field1 int not null, Field2 int not null)
```

This is how I check if the value already exists and insert it if necessary

```
merge MyTable as t
using (@Field1, @Field2) as s (Field1,Field2)
on (t.Field1=s.Field1)
when not matched then
    insert (Field1,Field2) values (s.Field1,s.Field2);
```

Getting the identity value when the record didn't already exist in the table can be done by adding:

```
output Inserted.MyTableId
```

but what if the record was already in the table (ie if there was a match)?

The only way I found is to query the table after executing the Merge statement:

```
select MyTableId from MyTable where Field1=@Field1
```

Is there a way to get the identity value directly from the Merge?

Answer (score 41):

In the case when the record already exists, you can store the matched id into a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @MatchedId INTEGER;

MERGE MyTable as t
....
....
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @MatchedId = t.MyTableId;
```

**UPDATE:**
Here's a full example. This demonstrates one way:

```
DECLARE @UpdateVariable bit
DECLARE @ChangeResult TABLE (ChangeType VARCHAR(10), Id INTEGER)
DECLARE @Data TABLE (Id integer IDENTITY(1,1), Val VARCHAR(10))
INSERT @Data ([Val]) VALUES ('A');

MERGE @data AS TARGET
USING (SELECT 'A' AS Val UNION ALL SELECT 'B' AS Val) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.Val = SOURCE.Val
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([Val])
    VALUES (SOURCE.Val)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET @UpdateVariable = 1
OUTPUT $action, inserted.Id INTO @ChangeResult;

SELECT * FROM @data
SELECT * FROM @ChangeResult
```

Points to note are:

- $action will give you what type of action was performed for a row (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
- @ChangeResult table will hold the info as to what types of changes were made
- for the WHEN MATCHED case, I am basically setting a dummy variable. This doesn't serve any purpose here other than to ensure the UPDATE path gets hit to generate the UPDATE row in the output. i.e. that @UpdateVariable is not used for anything else. If you actually wanted to update the existing row, then you'd put a proper UPDATE in here, but in the case where you don't want to actually UPDATE the existing row, then this "dummy" update seems to be required.

Comment: Thanks Adrian but if there is 'no matched' then how do you get the new identity value into @MatchedId?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes this would work but it looks like it's a lot more code than just doing "select MyTableId from MyTable where Field1=@Field1" after the Merge (obviously it depends on the size of the real table etc). I was just hoping there was a 'built-in' solution in the Merge statement which would return the identity value in both cases (matched or no matched).

Comment: `OUTPUT INSERTED.ID` (no `INTO`) returns the identity value in both cases.

Answer (score 34):

Here is an alternative and slightly simpler approach (in my opinion):

```
DECLARE @Id [int];

MERGE INTO [MyTable] AS [t]
USING (VALUES
  (@FieldA, @FieldB)
)
 AS [x] (FieldA, FieldB)
 ON [t].[FieldA] = [x].[FieldA]
AND [t].[FieldB] = [x].[FieldB]
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT (FieldA, FieldB)
    VALUES (FieldA, FieldB)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @Id = [t].[Id]

IF @Id IS NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Id = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as [int]);
END
SELECT @Id;
```

If the merge statement resulted in a match then `@Id` will be set to the identity of the matching row.  In the event of no match, the new row will have been inserted with its new identity ready to be selected from `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

Comment: Doesn't support multiple row inserts

Comment: Is there no way to get the inserted or the found Id in one statement?

Answer (score 7):

Here other alternative:

```
DECLARE @FakeVar BIT

MERGE MyTable AS T
USING (VALUES(@Field1, @Field2)) AS S (Field1, Field2)
    ON (T.Field1 = S.Field1)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (Field1, Field2)
    VALUES (S.Field1, T.Field2)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET @FakeVar = NULL -- do nothing, only force "an update" to ensure output on updates
OUTPUT INSERTED.MyTableId  ;
```

If you check the OUPUT doc

> INSERTED
> Is a column prefix that specifies the value added by the insert or update operation.

you only need to do "something" on the update set clause

Answer (score 0):

When a `Merge` has *existing* insert and an update code, the update most likely requires a primary key id. That value is generally passed to the stored procedure as a separate variable. Since that variable is null on a insert and has a value on an update, it is no issue to get the last insert with `Ident_Current` targeting the insert table.

###### Example to Merge into a `Project` table

```
Merge info.Project as Target
  ...  
 on @projectId  = TARGET.ProjectId
When not matched then
 ...         -- Insert
When matched then
 ...         -- Update
;

 if (@projectId is null)
   set @projectId = IDENT_CURRENT('info.Project')
```