# Insert scope identity of inserted table into another table while performing multiple insertion of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm Inserting record from temp table into table.
#temptab is temporary table and T_Sample is my table

```
#temptab   //Temporary table
```

| ID | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ONE |
| 2 | TWO |
| 3 | THREE |
| 4 | FOUR |
| 5 | FIVE |
| 6 | SIX |
| 7 | SEVEN |
| . | . |

```
T_Sample //1st table
```

| SampleID | SampleData |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ONE |
| 2 | TWO |
| 3 | THREE |
| 4 | FOUR |
| 5 | FIVE |
| 6 | SIX |
| 7 | SEVEN |
| . | . |

I'm selecting records from temptab and inserting using select query as shown below

```
INSERT INTO TABLE T_Sample(SampleData)
SELECT DATA FROM #temptab
```

I want to use T_Sample table scope identity of each insertion and want to insert into another table.

```
T_ScopeTab
```

| ScopeID | SampleID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 7 |
| . | . |

How can do this with help of looping or similar like that?

Comment: Fix your tags. You can't be using both mysql and sql-server.

Comment: Your sample output is just a sequence of counting numbers.  You may want to add other sample data.

Comment: If I understand your question, you can probably do what you want with a MERGE statement with an OUTPUT clause

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10650776/how-do-you-get-the-identity-value-after-using-merge-when-there-is-a-match

Comment: @JamesCasey +1 for the `OUTPUT` clause but -1 for `MERGE`. [`MERGE` is riddle with bugs](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) and should be avoided in production code.

Comment: I agree on merge being bad. But you do need it if you need to link the inserted id to something that isn't actually being inserted. Not sure if that's the case here as the question is kind of unclear

Comment: Doubting myself on this now, will test when I get a chance